# In list, create link to a document in a library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, library, links

I have a library that holds documents, of course.  I also have a list that (in each item) has a few columns that lookup from that library's document properties.  What I'm trying to do now is create a link to the document (in the library) in the list.  I've tried looking at another lookup column for this, but I can't make that work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a hyperlink field and a workflow to your target list.

When an item is updated, check if the lookup field has a value. If it is not blank, update the hyperlink field to have the server relative url from the lookup list:
[image]
`Filename` here is the hyperlink column.

Comment: Please clarify - The instructions state "When an item is updated, check if the lookup field has a value. ".   This means I need to add a lookup column - but should I add it to the LIST or add it to the LIBRARY?

Comment: The only thing you would need to add is a hyperlink column, your question stated that you already had a lookup defined. What I am referring to as the "target list" is the LIST - not the LIBRARY. That is where you want the link to display right?

Comment: Yes.  I initially tried to do this using Nintex Workflow, but ended up doing it just like you showed in SPD.  It does indeed work, thank you.  On a related note, is there a way to shorten the link displayed? (In know in HTML we'd show something like <a href="www.whatever.com">DISPLAYED TEXT</a>.  Ideas?

Comment: Glad to help! I think you must build a custom string to do that - it should be in the format "hyperlink, display text" (without quotation marks)

Answer (score 1):

To create a link to the document (in the library) in the list, there are some options:

1. Create a hyperlink column in the list.
2. Use the "Attach File" option from the actions menu.
3. Create a lookup column type. In the "Get information form:" select the document library you wish to link to.

Reference:

https://www.epmpartners.com.au/blog/how-to-link-a-list-item-to-a-document-library-document/